How to make the scrollbar transition gradually?
I am trying to re-create macOS scrollbar.
* {
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 8px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Standardized Properties */
  @supports not selector(::-webkit-scrollbar) {
    scrollbar-color: gray transparent;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
  }

  &[data-scrollbar-thumb="false"]::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  &[data-scrollbar-thumb="true"]::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}

This is the current result:

Meanwhile, this is desired result:

As you can see, in my implementation scrollbar just blinks ignoring my request to ease-in-out.
How do I make the transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out; work here?

Next time, please use the code snippet feature to make it easier to modify and reproduce.

Share your html too, so we can check.

You must use @property and make a variable which holds the scrollbar colour.
@property --scrollbar-colour {
  syntax: "<color>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: transparent;
}

Then you set the scrollbar colour to that, set it to a darker colour instead of the scrollbar directly, and set your transition to it.

Thanks! That's the same solution that I ended up implementing. Appreciate you sharing it. https://glama.ai/blog/2024-10-25-customizing-scrollbar-using-css
